# Sharepoint date manipulation and filtering

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, date

I'm having a real problem trying to filter a sharepoint list by date.  I want to produce a list of months/years where for each entry there is a count from the list, where the counts include dates that are greater than or equal to the 15th of that month, or less than the 15th of the following month.  I can do this fine for any month except for December, where I want the count to go from 15 Dec 2009 to 14 Jan 2010 (for example).  I really cannot see why there should be any difference as I am using the same method.  If anyone can see a mistake in my code, or a better way of doing it, I would be extremely grateful.

```
<xsl:template name="generateTable">
      <xsl:param name="numMonths" />
        <xsl:param name="Rows" />
        <xsl:param name="dvt_Rows" />
        <xsl:param name="tday" select="$startDay" />
        <xsl:param name="tmonth" select="($startMonth + msxsl:node-set($numMonths)-1) mod 12 + 1" />
        <xsl:param name="tyear" select="$startYear + floor(($numMonths+msxsl:node-set($startMonth)-1) div 12)" />
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="concat($tday,'/',$tmonth,'/',$tyear)"/>

        <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($date),3081,'MMMM yyyy')"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$tmonth=12">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows[1]/Row[(
                                    (ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) )=(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( $date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) ) 
                                    and number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Date), 3081, 'dd'),1,2)) &gt;=$startDay)])+
                                    count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows[1]/Row[(
                concat(string(number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ),1,2))+11),' ',
                string(number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'MM yyyy'),4))-1))=string(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( $date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) ) 
                and number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Date), 3081, 'dd'),1,2)) &lt;$startDay)])"/>      
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows[1]/Row[(
                                    (ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) )=(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( $date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) ) 
                                    and number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Date), 3081, 'dd'),1,2)) &gt;=$startDay)])+
                                    count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows[1]/Row[(
                concat(string(number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'MM yyyy' ),1,2))-1),
                substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( @Date ) , 3081, 'MM yyyy'),3,6))=(ddwrt:FormatDateTime ( string ( $date ) , 3081, 'M yyyy' ) ) 
                and number(substring(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Date), 3081, 'dd'),1,2)) &lt;$startDay)])"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($numMonths) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:call-template name="generateTable">
          <xsl:with-param name="numMonths" select="msxsl:node-set($numMonths)-1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="dvt_Rows"/>   
          <xsl:with-param name="Rows"/> 
      </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>


</xsl:template>
```

In the code, tday, tmonth and tyear are todays date in d/m/y, numMonths is a variable to hold the number of months required in the table, and startDay is 15.

As far as I can see, the adding of 11 months to the Date fields works, but extracting the year, changing it to a number and subtracting 1, is where the problem seems to be. But I can't get it to work, so I have completely run out of simple ideas.

The XML document is the Sharepoint list and I don't know how to share it as pure XML. The only reference I make to the XML is /dsQueryResponse/Rows[1]/Row which selects rows in the Sharepoint list, and uses the Date field (@Date) to perform the filter. Does this help at all?

I'm using Sharepoint 2007, and I started by using the Sharepoint Designer to obtain the Sharepoint list by inserting a dataFormWebPart.  It's then possible to access the Sharepoint list in the XSLT by using xpath, /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row which references all rows in the list. (I have added [1] in my code here to reference a specific list as I have two list data sources).

I would prefer to filter the list in Sharepoint first, and considered that first, but maybe I am doing something wrong, as I can't get that to produce exactly what I want - which includes zeros when there are no entries for a specific month, as well as the >=15 of the month filter. My method almost works which is why it is so frustrating, but I would welcome any alternatives especially if they are simpler and/or quicker.
Thanks

Comment: Could you, please, provide us with the XML document (as minimal as possible that would still serve to illustrate the problem)? I suspect that there might be a much simpler solution, but need an XML document to work with.

Comment: Couple of questions.. What version of SharePoint? How are you getting the data from the SharePoint list?  Also, why are you filtering the SharePoint list using XSLT? Wouldn't you want to query the list (to filter the rows) and then transform the result using XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

As example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kDateByYearAndMonth" match="date"
             use="translate(substring(.,1,7),'-','') -
                  (15 > substring(.,9,2)) * (1 + (substring(.,6,2)='01') * 88)"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="date[count(. |
                                                key('kDateByYearAndMonth',
                                                    translate(substring(.,1,7),'-','') -
                                                    (15 > substring(.,9,2)) *
                                                    (1 + (substring(.,6,2)='01') * 88)
                                                   )[1]
                                               ) = 1]"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:variable name="vKey" select="translate(substring(.,1,7),'-','') -
                  (15 > substring(.,9,2)) * (1 + (substring(.,6,2)='01') * 88)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vDates" select="key('kDateByYearAndMonth',$vKey)"/>
        <group year="{substring($vKey,1,4)}" month="{substring($vKey,5,2)}"
               count="{count($vDates)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$vDates"/>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
<date>2001-01-01T00:15:00</date>
<date>2001-01-02T00:15:00</date>
<date>2001-02-03T00:15:00</date>
<date>2001-02-04T00:15:00</date>
<date>2002-03-05T00:15:00</date>
<date>2002-03-06T00:15:00</date>
<date>2002-04-07T00:15:00</date>
<date>2002-04-08T00:15:00</date>
<date>2003-05-09T00:15:00</date>
<date>2003-05-10T00:15:00</date>
<date>2003-06-11T00:15:00</date>
<date>2003-06-12T00:15:00</date>
<date>2004-07-13T00:15:00</date>
<date>2004-07-14T00:15:00</date>
<date>2004-08-15T00:15:00</date>
<date>2004-08-16T00:15:00</date>
<date>2005-09-17T00:15:00</date>
<date>2005-09-18T00:15:00</date>
<date>2005-10-19T00:15:00</date>
<date>2005-10-20T00:15:00</date>
<date>2006-11-21T00:15:00</date>
<date>2006-11-22T00:15:00</date>
<date>2006-12-23T00:15:00</date>
<date>2006-12-24T00:15:00</date>
<date>2007-01-25T00:15:00</date>
<date>2007-01-26T00:15:00</date>
<date>2007-02-27T00:15:00</date>
<date>2007-02-28T00:15:00</date>
<date>2008-03-29T00:15:00</date>
<date>2008-03-30T00:15:00</date>
<date>2008-04-31T00:15:00</date>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<result>
    <group year="2000" month="12" count="2">
        <date>2001-01-01T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2001-01-02T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2001" month="1" count="2">
        <date>2001-02-03T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2001-02-04T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2002" month="2" count="2">
        <date>2002-03-05T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2002-03-06T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2002" month="3" count="2">
        <date>2002-04-07T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2002-04-08T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2003" month="4" count="2">
        <date>2003-05-09T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2003-05-10T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2003" month="5" count="2">
        <date>2003-06-11T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2003-06-12T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2004" month="6" count="2">
        <date>2004-07-13T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2004-07-14T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2004" month="8" count="2">
        <date>2004-08-15T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2004-08-16T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2005" month="9" count="2">
        <date>2005-09-17T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2005-09-18T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2005" month="10" count="2">
        <date>2005-10-19T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2005-10-20T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2006" month="11" count="2">
        <date>2006-11-21T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2006-11-22T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2006" month="12" count="2">
        <date>2006-12-23T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2006-12-24T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2007" month="1" count="2">
        <date>2007-01-25T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2007-01-26T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2007" month="2" count="2">
        <date>2007-02-27T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2007-02-28T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2008" month="3" count="2">
        <date>2008-03-29T00:15:00</date>
        <date>2008-03-30T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
    <group year="2008" month="4" count="1">
        <date>2008-04-31T00:15:00</date>
    </group>
</result>
```

**Note**: The month' start day is "hardcode", because there can't be variable reference in `xsl:key/@use`.

**Editt**: Better key calculation.

Comment: Thanks. I've used your substring-only function idea to replace my long-winded string(number(substring(etc))) function and that seems to work. Not sure why that should be the case.